# Google script: Copy range from Sheet1 to last empty row at sheet2 and delete rows

Tags: google-sheets, copy

That would be easy if it was VBA. But it's not,
What I want to do with script for a google spreadsheet I got, is the following:

1. Range is dynamic. `Sheet1 A7:I(i)` where i is the last row from sheet1 (or if you prefer, rows 7 - i from sheet1, makes no difference)
2. This range has to be paste as values at the next empty row of sheet2
3. Then i need to delete rows 7-i from sheet1

VBA code could be like this:

```
Dim LastRow_Sheet1 As Long
LastRow_Sheet1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim LastRow_Sheet2 As Long
LastRow_Sheet2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Dim Rng As Range
With Sheet1
    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(LastRow_Sheet1, 9))
End With

Rng.Copy
Sheet2.Cells(LastRow_Sheet2, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheet1.Rows("7:" & LastRow_Sheet1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that's what you want.  Sorry, I forgot to change it to a column. And I arbitrarily selected column1 in Sheet2.

```
function copyFromSheet1ToSheet2()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(7,1,sh1.getLastRow()-6,9);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var A=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<vA1[i].length;j++)
    {
      A.push([vA1[i][j]]);
    }
  }
  var rg2=sh2.getRange('A:A');
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA2.length;i++)
  {
    if(!vA2[i][0])
    {
      var nextRowInColumn1=i+1;
      var org=sh2.getRange(nextRowInColumn1,1,A.length,1);
      org.setValues(A);
      break;
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++)
  {
    sh1.deleteRow(6 + vA1.length - i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want this to do (pastes rows from sheet 1 to last row at sheet 2 horizontically not vertically) but i will study this script and try to solve it alone ;) Since i got a pattern now on what it looks like

Comment: See edits.  I made it a column array and append in to bottom of column1